# Conditional expectation with respect to union of two sigma-algebra

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $\mathscr{F}_1$ and $\mathscr{F}_2$ be two independent (sub)sigma-algebra,$X$ be a random variable with $\mathbb{E}X<\infty$.

What we want to find is the relationship between $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathscr{F_1})$,$\mathbb{E}(X|\mathscr{F_2})$, and $\mathbb{E}(X|\sigma(\mathscr{F_1}\cup\mathscr{F_2}))$. Some assumption such as the measurability of $X$ could be added.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "the relationship between [...]" ? What kind of result do you expect : an inequality, measurability, something else...? And what did you try ?

Comment: Since $F_1\subseteq \sigma(F_1\cup F_2)$ we have (almost surely) $$E[X|F_1]=E[E[X|\sigma(F_1\cup F_2)]|F_1]$$ which is a version of the standard "tower property." You can do a simple example with $X=f(Y,Z)$ and $F_1=\sigma(Y)$ and $F_2=\sigma(Z)$, in which case $X=E[X|\sigma(F_1\cup F_2)]$ almost surely.

Comment: For the random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $E[|X|]<\infty$, the arxiv paper below proves that for any versions of $E[X|F_1], E[X|F_2], E[X|\sigma(F_1\cup F_2)]$,  there exist random variables $Y_i:\Omega\rightarrow[0,1]$, where $Y_i$ is $F_i$-measurable for $i \in \{1,2\}$, such that $$E[X|F_1]=g_1(Y_1), \quad E[X|F_2]=g_2(Y_2), \quad E[X|\sigma(F_1\cup F_2)]=h(Y_1,Y_2)$$ for some Borel measurable functions $g_i:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $h:[0,1]^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.02345.pdf

Answer (score -2):

For what it's worth:
$$\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr {F_1}](\omega_1)=\int\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{F}_1\circ\mathscr{F}_2](\omega_1,\omega_2)dP_\Omega(\omega_2)$$
Where $\mathscr{F}_1\circ\mathscr{F}_2$ is the $\sigma$-algebra associated with the product space $\Omega(\mathscr{F}_1)\times\Omega(\mathscr{F}_2)$.
And where it is also fulfilled that $\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(\mathscr{F}_1\cup\mathscr{F}_2)](\omega)=\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{F}_1\circ\mathscr{F}_2](\omega,\omega)$.

Comment: I think the OP is assuming a single sample space $\Omega$, so $F_1$ and $F_2$ are two different sigma algebras on $\Omega$ and $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a random variable. Then $E[X|F_1]$ and $E[X|\sigma(F_1\cup F_2)]$ would both be random variables (hence functions of just  $\omega \in \Omega$).

Comment: Does anyone think otherwise?

Comment: You seem to be suggesting that there is a sample space $\Omega(F_1)$ for sigma algebra 1, and a sample space $\Omega(F_2)$ for sigma algebra 2. And you are somehow making $X$ a random variable on both $\Omega$ (and so a function of $\omega$) and $\Omega(F_1)\times\Omega(F_2)$ (and so a function of $(\omega_1, \omega_2)$). This does not make sense.

Comment: Defining $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{F}_1\circ\mathscr{F}_2]$ is not difficult.
But in order not to go into greater depths I will tell you that $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{F}_1\circ\mathscr{F}_2]$ can be understood as the result of applying the Doob-Dynkin-Lemma to $ \mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(\mathscr{F}_1\cup\mathscr{F}_2)]$

Comment: We can consider variables $Y_1:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega(\mathscr{F}_1)$ and $Y_2:\Omega\rightarrow\Omega(\mathscr{F}_2)$. By the Doob-Dynkin-Lemma:
$$\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(\mathscr{F}_1\cup\mathscr{F}_2)]=\mathbb{E}[X|Y_1,Y_2]=f(Y_1,Y_2)$$
$\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{F}_1\circ\mathscr{F}_2]$ is precisely $f$.

Comment: In a nutshell: $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{F}_1\circ\mathscr{F}_2]=\mathbb{E}[X'|\mathscr{F}_1\circ\mathscr{F}_2]$. Where $X'$ is any variable defined on $\Omega'=\Omega(\mathscr{F}_1)\times\Omega(\mathscr{F}_2)$ (con $P_{\Omega'}(A\times B)=P_\Omega(A\cap B)$) that coincides with $X$ on the diagonal: $X(\omega)=X'(\omega,\omega)$

Comment: A function cannot have two domains. If $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ then $E[X|\mathcal{H}]$ only makes sense if $\mathcal{H}$ is a sigma algebra on $\Omega$, not on some other set $\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$ that is different from $\Omega$. Since $F_1$ and  $F_1 \otimes F_2$ seem to be sigma algebras on different sets, it does not make sense to  speak of both $E[X|F_1]$ and $E[X|F_1 \otimes F_2]$.

Comment: The above is the definition of $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{F}_1\circ\mathscr{F}_2]$.

Comment: I now understand that you intend the "in a nutshell" comment to be a _definition_ of the $E[X|F_1\otimes F_2]$ expression (without a special definition, it looks like that expression makes mistake about the domain of $X$). It may be easier to understand if you just use $X'$ anywhere it is needed (without making special definitions).

Comment: As an aside, you may be interested in my arxiv paper that extends the Doob-Dynkin result to something a  bit stronger: If $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $\sigma(F_1\cup F_2)$ measurable then $X=f(Y_1,Y_2)$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable and $Y_i:\Omega\rightarrow[0,1]$ are $F_i$-measurable for $i\in\{1,2\}$. It is different from what you state above in that $Y_1, Y_2$ are random variables rather than random elements. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.02345.pdf

Comment: I will read it with interest, thank you.